# How Can I convert multiple lines text divided with BR tag, in an ordered html list using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists

How Can I convert multiple lines text divided with BR tag, in an ordered html list.

this is html source:

```
<div class="Container">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci
<br>
ng elit. Curabitur vulputate, est nec iaculis lobortis, libero v
<br>
elit pharetra nulla, eget tristique felis lacus ac orci. Vivamus ut
<br>
accumsan leo. Vestibulum ac velit adipiscing, tempor purus
<br>
quis, condimentum lectus. Morbi m
<br>
alesuada, lectus non gravida pretium,
</div>
```

and this is the desired ouput:

```
<div class ="Container">

<ol>

<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci</li>

<li>ng elit. Curabitur vulputate, est nec iaculis lobortis, libero </li>

<li>elit pharetra nulla, eget tristique felis lacus ac orci. Vivamus ut</li>

<li>accumsan leo. Vestibulum ac velit adipiscing, tempor purus</li>

<li> quis, condimentum lectus. Morbi m</li>

<li>alesuada, lectus non gravida pretium,</li>

</ol>

</div>
```

Notice please, there is no `<br>` tag before the first line(this a dynamically generated content.)

Comment: So you're looking for what then, a JavaScript solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var content = $('.Container').html().split('<br>');
$('.Container').empty().append('<ul>');
for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    $('.Container ul').append('<li>' + content[i] + '</li>')
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/z76jf/)**

Produces:

```
<div class="Container">
    <ul>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci</li>
        <li>ng elit. Curabitur vulputate, est nec iaculis lobortis, libero v</li>
        <li>elit pharetra nulla, eget tristique felis lacus ac orci. Vivamus ut</li>
        <li>accumsan leo. Vestibulum ac velit adipiscing, tempor purus</li>
        <li>quis, condimentum lectus. Morbi m</li>
        <li>alesuada, lectus non gravida pretium,</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly.

Comment: This makes the assumption that jQuery is used, which wasn't defined in the original question. See my answer for an answer free of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Grab the html from the Container element by doing this:

```
var containerHtml = $('.container').html();
```

Next, take that string and split it on '`<br>`' which gives you an array.

```
var containerHtmlArray = containerHtml.split('<br>');
```

Finally, recreate the container content by looping through the array:

```
var newContainerHtml = '<ol>';

for (var i = 0; i < containerHtmlArray.length-1; i++) {
    newContainerHtml += '<li>'+ containerHtmlArray[i] + '</li>';
}

newContainerHtml += '</ol>';

$('.container').html(newContainerHtml);
```

Something like this should work, there are more elegant solutions to this problem but this is the most obvious solution I believe.

Answer (score 0):

To expand the knowledge, you can also use regexp and jQuery's HTML processing with a one hit wonder.

```
$('.Container').html('<ol><li>' + $('.Container').html().replace(/<br( \/)?>/g, '</li><li>') + '</li></ol>');
```

This takes into account also that special case that there are no line breaks, but only one line.

Update: JSFiddle for your convenience: http://jsfiddle.net/ckLZV/

Second update: I made the silly assumption that you would use jQuery. Here is a pure JS version:

```
var containers = document.getElementsByClassName('Container');

for (var i = 0 ; i < containers.length; i++) {
  containers[i].innerHTML = '<ol><li>' + containers[i].innerHTML.toString().replace(/<br.*?>/ig, '</li><li>') + '</li></ol>'
}
```

And respective JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tfE5X/1/